# Define the draw_histogram() function which is passed a Python dictionary as a parameter

Tags: python

when run my code, it always shows nothing. I am so confused  as to what wrong about my code. Here is what I coded:

```
def draw_histogram(histogram_dict):
    all_keys = list(histogram_dict.keys())
    all_keys.sort()
    for key in all_keys:
       stars = "*" * histogram_dict[key] 
       print(key, ":", stars)
def test_draw_histogram():
    print("1.")
    draw_histogram({'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 5})
    print()

    print("2.")
    draw_histogram({'a': 0, 'c': 5, 'b': 7, 'f': 0})
```

And the output should be something like this:

```
 a: **

 b: *****

 c: *******
```

Comment: That code needs to be reformatted.
Looks like that should work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw_histogram(histogram_dict):
    all_keys = list(histogram_dict.keys())
    all_keys.sort()
    for key in all_keys:
        stars = "*" * histogram_dict[key]
        print(key, ":", stars)

def test_draw_histogram():
    print("1.")
    draw_histogram({'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 5})
    print("\n")
    print("2.")
    draw_histogram({'a': 0, 'c': 5, 'b': 7, 'f': 0})

test_draw_histogram()
```

You need to call the function you've just defined.